# How to join two tables with the same values but with different column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two tables:

| reference_id | reference_date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 2012-01-01 | 14.35 |
| 205 | 2012-03-02 | 10.02 |
| 325 | 2012-04-02 | 5.40 |
| 14 | 2012-06-20 | 7.68 |

| ticket-reference_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 112 | 2 |
| 205 | 4 |
| 325 | 7 |
| 14 | 5 |

I need to join the values of the reference_id and ticket_reference_id preserving the column names.

So that, I need to have the next result:

| reference_id | reference_date | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 2012-01-01 | 14.35 | 2 |
| 205 | 2012-03-02 | 10.02 | 4 |
| 325 | 2012-04-02 | 5.40 | 7 |
| 14 | 2012-06-20 | 7.68 | 5 |

I tried to do it with the next code but it doesnt join the values and it creates column reference_id and ticket-reference_id:

```
    result = df1.merge(right=df2, how='left', left_on='reference_id', right_on='ticket-reference_id', copy=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try renaming the column to match before merge:

```py
result = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'ticket-reference_id': 'reference_id'}),
                   how='left',
                   on='reference_id', 
                   copy=False)
print(result)
```

`result`:

```
   reference_id reference_date  price  quantity
0           112     2012-01-01  14.35         2
1           205     2012-03-02  10.02         4
2           325     2012-04-02   5.40         7
3            14     2012-06-20   7.68         5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But one more question ..Is it possible to do it without changing the name of the column? Maybe there is a function that joins values from two columns?

Comment: `df2.rename` returns a copy of the DataFrame. The DataFrame associated with the variable df2 is unaffected by this code.